# R factor dataframe of coordinates

Tags: r, coordinates, factors

I have a dataframe and a column of ordered pairs of (latitude, longitude) as factors within that dataframe that I would like to extract into columns of just the latitude and longitude values separately into numerics. How would I get rid of the commas and parentheses and place the factors into their own columns as numbers?

Comment: As was mentioned in your previous question, please make this question reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically after `set.seed(1)`), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 1):

Several ways, but I'll focus on `strcapture`. My sample data:

```r
somecoords <- c("(1.1,2.2)","(3.3,4.4)")
# if not 'character', then
somecoords <- as.character(somecoords)
```

`strcapture` starts with a vector of strings and returns a `data.frame`:

```r
strcapture("\\D*(-?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*),(-?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*)\\D?.*$",
           somecoords, proto = list(num1=0, num2=0))
#   num1 num2
# 1  1.1  2.2
# 2  3.3  4.4
```

Regex walk-through:

- `\\D*` zero or more non-digit characters
- `(...)` a capture group, saved by `strcapture` into a column
- `-?` a literal dash/hyphen, optional
- `[0-9]+` one or more digits
- `\\.?` literal dot, optional, in case there are whole-number coordinates in your data
- `[0-9]*` zero or more digits
- `,` literal comma
- `\\D?.*` optional non-digit character, followed by zero or more of anything
- `$` end of string (perhaps not required, since `.*` should have expanded fully